# How to clear text from file in real time (java)

Tags: file, text, filewriter

I've searched around but haven't find the solution to suit my purposes...
I've seen solutions like: delete the file and recreate it and such, but I need to erase all previous text while program is running.

My code is near that solution.
As you can see in code below (i am noob "programer", excuse me for trivial code) I already have a file. Text is already in it. When I run the program through CMD, I can either add new text with Scanner (it gets appended), quit the program by hitting 'q' character, or I can delete/erase text by typing "delete". Well, it turns out that previous text gets deleted, but text imputed in "this session" does NOT!
Meaning, if i write to console:

This is test.

I want to delete these 2 sentences.

*delete*

This is text that should be printed.

*q*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadWriteFile{
public static void main (String[]agrs) throws IOException{
    try{

        Scanner vhod = new Scanner (System.in);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Filee.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for(int i = 1; i <100; i++){
            String s = vhod.nextLine();
                if(s.charAt(0)=='q'){
                    i = 111;
                }

                else if (s.equals("delete")){
                    FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("Filee.txt");
                }

                else {
                    bw.write(s);
                }
            }
        bw.close();
    }

    catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The program returns all 3 sentences ('q' & 'delete' are not printed to console off course, they are commands), whereas it should only return last one: "This is text that should be printed".

I hope I was clear enough and someone will understand my question.
Thank you nice people for helping us beginners fight java coding :)

Comment: Why don't you want to just delete it and create a new one?

Comment: So you don't want to clear a file, you want to delete parts of a file, right?  You should rename your title.

Comment: Lets say i have some text in that file from before. I run the program and want to add some fresh text, at some point i decide to delete the previous stuff. i hit "delete" and continue typing without leaving the program. (i run it from cmd...). Is there any other command to delete text from file? I would like to have it like a function dedicated to a key stroke. Like 'q' is for exit the program, 'd' for example or "delete" string would mean erase all text.